# Counting unique strings in one column per date

Tags: powershell

First, my data looks something like this (added more lines for clarification)

```
Time, Type, Text
11/1/2016 10:52, LOGIN, User domain\userID1 has logged in
11/1/2016 10:53, LOGIN, User domain\userID2 has logged in
11/1/2016 10:53, AGENT, Agent has restarted (or whatever, not important)
10/31/2016 07:12, LOGIN, User domain\userID2 has logged in
10/30/2016 07:12, LOGIN, User domain\userID2 has logged in
10/30/2016 06:21, LOGIN, User domain\userID2 has logged in
10/30/2016 05:14, LOGIN, User domain\userID2 has logged in
```

I am trying to create a powershell script that will list the number of unique logins per day. I want to see:

```
11/1/2016, 2
10/31/2016, 1
10/30/2016, 1
```

### The code I have for now..

```
$ListOfDates = Get-Content 'C:\path\data.csv'
$ArrayOfDates =@()

ForEach ($LogEntry in $ListOfDates) {
 $DateSplit = $LogEntry -split '[\\ , ]'
   If (-not ($ArrayOfDates -contains $DateSplit[0])) {
      $ArrayOfDates += $DateSplit[0]
 }
}

$string = Get-Content 'c:\path\data.csv' |
Where-Object {$_.'Time' -contains $ArrayOfDates[1]} |
Sort-Object -Property 'Time'
```

---

The $ArrayOfDates does return the individual dates, so that seems to work fine. I'm just not sure how to do the check with the variable of the Date and then count unique entries for that specific date.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a few hours of trying to figure things out and help from your answers here as well as a colleague of mine. Here's the script I ended up with, for reference.

It does a little more than what was asked in the question, but it definitely completes the task at hand too.

Hope it helps someone else in their efforts of doing something similar.

```
# STEP 1 start. This part takes the extract "export.csv" and splits the dates and usernames to managable data for the next step. 
# It also creates a new csv "Filteredcsv.csv" which contains only records we are interested in checking

# Create the Filteredcsv.csv with headlines "time", "user" and "composite". Composite is a combination of the time and user data, so I can get the unique logins per user and day.
Add-Content Filteredcsv.csv "time,user,composite"


# Grab the important information from export.csv and sort the entries by time
$string = Import-Csv 'export.csv' |
Select-Object -Property 'Event Type','Time','Event Text' |
Sort-Object -Property 'Time' -Descending


# For every line in the base csv, split out username and date only and write to the Filteredcsv.csv file
ForEach ($user in $string) {
$useronly = $user.'Event Text' -split '[\\, ]'
$dateonly = $user.Time -split '[ ]'

$dateonly[0] + ',' + $useronly[2] | Sort-Object -Property time -Descending | ft | Out-File 'Filteredcsv.csv' -Append ascii
}

## END STEP 1 of the script. We now have a Filteredcsv.csv with information we can use to sort out the login events per day.


## STEP 2 start. We will use the Filteredcsv.csv and count the amount of unique logins for each day in that file. 

# Variables used in step 2
$srcEvt = "Filteredcsv.csv" # source event file that was created in step 1
$lc = 0       # lc = license count to separate most frequent users; not used right now, but can be used if needed
$topUsers = "topuser2.csv"  #top users
$infrequentUsers ="user2b.csv" # All users - top users
$z2 = @()     # array to store infrequentusers user ids
$outLoginsByUser = "loginsPerUser.txt" #path to concurrent logins/user file
$outLoginsByDate = "loginsByDate.txt " #path to concurrent logins/day file


# $b is just a scratch csv to get our user lists
$a = Import-Csv $srcEvt
$b = $a | Group-Object -Property user | select-object -property Count,Name  | Sort-Object -property Count -Descending 
$b |Select-Object * -skip $lc| Export-Csv $infrequentUsers -NoTypeInformation -Force
$b | Select-Object * -first $lc| Export-Csv $topUsers -NoTypeInformation -Force

$z = import-csv $infrequentUsers


# loads the concurrent users into an array for searching
foreach ($y in $z) { 
$z2 += $y.Name
}


# Checks if the AD user is disabled and if so, discounts it from being counted
foreach ($c in $a) {
$activeUser = 'False'
  $user = get-aduser $c.user 
  $activeUser = $user.Enabled
  if (($z2 -contains $c.user) -and ($activeUser)) {$c.composite = $c.time + $c.user}
    else { $c.composite = ''}
}


# Write output to files, logins by date and by user
$b = $a |  sort-object -property composite -Unique
$b | Group-Object -Property user |  Sort-Object -Property count -Descending | ft | Out-File -FilePath $outLoginsByUser
$b | Group-Object -Property time | Sort-Object -Property count -Descending |ft | Out-File -FilePath $outLoginsByDate

## END Step 2 of the script


## START Step 3 of the script. Now that we have all the information we need, we just want to move it to a folder named by yesterday's date.

# create folder named after yesterdays date and move the files used in this script to that folder.
$yesterday = get-date -date $(Get-Date).AddDays(-1) -UFormat "%Y%m%d"
$foldername = 'c:\path\' + $yesterday

md $foldername

Mv 'export.csv' $foldername
Mv 'Filteredcsv.csv' $foldername
Mv 'loginsByDate.txt' $foldername
Mv 'loginsPerUser.txt' $foldername
Mv 'topuser2.csv' $foldername
Mv 'user2b.csv' $foldername


## END Step 3

## END Script
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Import-Csv data.csv | Where-Object {$_.Type -match 'LOGIN'} | 
                      Group-Object -Property { $_.Time.Split()[0] } | 
                      Select-Object Name, Count
```

If you're typing it at the prompt for interactive work, you might go for the shorter version:

```
ipcsv data.csv |? Type -match 'login' | group {$_.Time.Split()[0]} -NoElement
```

---

To comment on your original script, it's not going to work (easily) without the concept of a hashtable to link up each date with a count for that date. Just using arrays would be really fiddly.

Edit: Yes, this only gets total logins per day, not unique logins. Here's a version which gets unique logins:

```
Import-Csv data.csv |
       # Filter only the LOGIN entries, ignore 'AGENT' and so on
       Where-Object {$_.Type -match 'LOGIN'} | 

       # Group the lines by date (day only, ignoring the time)
       Group-Object -Property { $_.Time.Split()[0] } | 

       # For the results, each group is named for whatever you were grouping by
                        # so the group name is the date value 
       Select-Object @{
                        Name='Date'
                        Expression={$_.Name}
                      },

                        # to get unique logins, take all the things in each group
                        # Group those by a property which is calculated to get 'domain\userID1'
                        # and count how many of those groups there are
                     @{
                        Name='Unique Login Count'
                        Expression={
                            ($_.Group | Group-Object -Property { $_.Text.Split()[1] }).Count}
                        }
```

---

Where:

- Import-Csv is [`Import-Csv`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113341) (in module Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility)
- Where-Object is [`Where-Object`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113423)
- Group-Object is [`Group-Object`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113338) (in module Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility)
- Select is an alias for [`Select-Object`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113387) (in module Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility)

Comment: Thanks! That gets me the total logins per day, not unique. But it is so close to what I want that I can hopefully figure out the rest.

Comment: @Zleipner Oops, yes. Careless of me. I've added an updated version into my answer which, I think, gets unique logins.

Comment: Hmm, that made it a lot more complicated for me, and for some reason it still lists all logins per day. I am working on figuring it out though, trying to use Get-Unique cmdlet but not sure if that would even work. Haven't figured it out just yet at least.

Thanks again, you have definitely cut my time to get this running immensely.

Answer (score 0):

```
  import-csv C:\temp\test.csv | where type -EQ "LOGIN" | select *, @{Name="DateOnly";Expression={([datetime]$_.Time).ToShortDateString() }} | group DateOnly
```

Comment: That's just as good as the other answer, thanks. We'll see which one I find easier to use to sort out only unique entries per date. If/when I get it figured out, I will try to remember to post the result here too.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation [really helps](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.